# Android If Statements Not Working

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am currently developing an app that will require that the user enters their password to access the game. I have the following if statement but it will not work, as you can see from the if statements I have tried three different ways to get the match to equal true.

```
    EditText passInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordBox);
    CharSequence Password = passInput.getText();
    RelativeLayout loggedIn = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LoggedInLayout);
    RelativeLayout CreateUser = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.createUserLayout);
    Button loginBtt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createUser);
    String actualPass = password[x];

    System.out.println(Password + actualPass + passInput);

    if(Password.equals(actualPass)){

        System.out.println("They Matched!");
        loggedIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CreateUser.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loginBtt.setText("Create User");

    }else if(Password.toString() == actualPass.toString()){

        System.out.println("Second Match");

    }else if(Password == actualPass){

        System.out.println("Third Match");

    }else if(Password.equals(actualPass) == false){

    System.out.println("Wrong");
    incorrectPassword();
    System.out.println(Password);
    System.out.println(actualPass);

    }
```

When the user registers they are required to set a password. For testing I tried the password 'trst' but when inserted to the login page it comes back as being not correct. This is what my LogCat displays:

```
11-07 11:46:16.357: I/System.out(1998): Wrong
11-07 11:46:16.547: I/System.out(1998): trst
11-07 11:46:16.547: I/System.out(1998): trst
```

As you can see from the LogCat the inserted password and the actual password are identical but the program says they are not!

Comment: Use equals method for String comparison instead of ==

Comment: string comparison in Java have to be performed trough `equals` method (case sensitive) or `equalsIgnoreCase` (case insensitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 CharSequence Password = passInput.getText();
```

To

```
 String Password = passInput.getText().toString();
```

then

```
if(Password.equalsIgnorecase(actualPass)){

        System.out.println("They Matched!");
        loggedIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CreateUser.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loginBtt.setText("Create User");

    }else if(Password.equalsIgnorecase(actualPass.toString())){

        System.out.println("Second Match");

    }else if(Password.equalsIgnorecase(actualPass)){

        System.out.println("Third Match");

    }else if(!Password.equalsIgnorecase(actualPass)){

    System.out.println("Wrong");
    incorrectPassword();
    System.out.println(Password);
    System.out.println(actualPass);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you!! Changing it from a CharSequence to a String worked!

Comment: You can check my edited answer. Try to compare string using `equalsIgnorecase`.

Comment: Thanks, I would like it to be case sensitive though so I will keep it at .equals rather than .equalsIgnorecase.

Comment: yeah..its your choice. If my answer solves your issue then u can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.equals()` instead of `==` for checking if one `String` objects is equal to another. `==` returns `true` if two references are referencing the same object, while `.equals()` returns `true` if contents of two strings are identical.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this already but it appears that it wasn't working because I was trying to compare a String to a CharSequence

Comment: `String` is a class which implements `CharSequence` interface, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: That's odd. It worked as I was wanting it to when I changed it from a CharSequence to a String

Comment: @Alex try to use `.equals()` insted of `==`, keep `CharSequence` and see if it works. I tried to check equality of `String` and `CharSequence` and it works.

Answer (score 2):

try `Password.toString().equals(actualPass.toString())`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot not compare `CharSequence` with String using `equal()`.So change `CharSequence` to String by using this

```
String Password = passInput.getText().toString();
```